# What effect does Companion Fear have?

Tags: tyranny

My companions have both a Loyalty and Fear bar under Reputations.

So far it looks like Loyalty makes them more likely to open up to me about things, but I haven't seen anything opened up by Fear.

It looks like they are not opposites, I can have both Loyalty and Fear so I assume it is not "bad".

But what does Fear actually do?

Answer (score 1):

It's just another dialog state to get new options.

I once had an enemy offer Barik a chance to leave me and rejoin the disfavored, but his fear was high enough he stayed.